# task.loop in function is not showing any errors but also not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to make a function that takes the time of a time zone and uses a conditional statement that if a time hits the correct the specified criteria then it does send a message pinging 3 roles. However the function task loop is not working.

It does not show any errors, however it also does not do anything on the background. I have already updated the discord.py module so that is not the issue.

```
import os
import discord
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
import datetime
import pytz
import asyncio


intents = discord.Intents.default() 
intents.members = True
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '?',intents=intents) #sets prefix 
client.remove_command('help')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    await client.change_presence(status=discord.Status.do_not_disturb, activity= discord.Activity(name="Around ;)", type=discord.ActivityType.watching))
    print('ready')

@tasks.loop(minutes=1)
async def time_event():
    await client.wait_until_ready()
    while not client.is_closed:
        cst = datetime.datetime.now(tz=pytz.timezone('US/Central')).time()
        if cst.hour == 00 and cst.minute == 17:
            channel = client.get_channel(760182149839716423)
            await channel.send("<@&811801850771800134>")
            await channel.send("<@&811808231218610266>")
            await channel.send("<@&811802000463101963>")
        elif cst.hour == 19 and cst.minute == 40:
            channel = client.get_channel(760182149839716423)
            await channel.send("<@&811801850771800134>")
            await channel.send("<@&811808231218610266>")
            await channel.send("<@&811802000463101963>")
        elif cst.hour == 9 and cst.minute == 00:
            channel = client.get_channel(760182149839716423)
            await channel.send("<@&811801850771800134>")
            await channel.send("<@&811808231218610266>")
            await channel.send("<@&811802000463101963>")
        elif cst.hour == 13 and cst.minute == 00:
            channel = client.get_channel(760182149839716423)
            await channel.send("<@&811801850771800134>")
            await channel.send("<@&811808231218610266>")
            await channel.send("<@&811802000463101963>")
            break
        elif cst.hour == 18 and cst.minute == 00:
            channel = client.get_channel(760182149839716423)
            await channel.send("<@&811801850771800134>")
            await channel.send("<@&811808231218610266>")
            await channel.send("<@&811802000463101963>")
            break


time_event.start()
client.run('Token')
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know too much about asyncio.
But I know something that might work for you

```py
import os
import discord
from discord.ext import commands, tasks # you don't need to import tasks
import datetime
import pytz
import asyncio


intents = discord.Intents.default() 
intents.members = True
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '?',intents=intents) #sets prefix 
client.remove_command('help')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    await client.change_presence(status=discord.Status.do_not_disturb, activity= discord.Activity(name="Around ;)", type=discord.ActivityType.watching))
    print('ready')

async def time_event():
    await client.wait_until_ready()
    while not client.is_closed:
        await asyncio.sleep(5) # Pause the loop (not the whole program) for a certain amount of time (in seconds)
        # You must use await asyncio.sleep otherwise the program will not run well (at least one second)
        cst = datetime.datetime.now(tz=pytz.timezone('US/Central')).time()
        if cst.hour == 00 and cst.minute == 17:
            channel = client.get_channel(760182149839716423)
            await channel.send("<@&811801850771800134>")
            await channel.send("<@&811808231218610266>")
            await channel.send("<@&811802000463101963>")
        elif cst.hour == 19 and cst.minute == 40:
            channel = client.get_channel(760182149839716423)
            await channel.send("<@&811801850771800134>")
            await channel.send("<@&811808231218610266>")
            await channel.send("<@&811802000463101963>")
        elif cst.hour == 9 and cst.minute == 00:
            channel = client.get_channel(760182149839716423)
            await channel.send("<@&811801850771800134>")
            await channel.send("<@&811808231218610266>")
            await channel.send("<@&811802000463101963>")
        elif cst.hour == 13 and cst.minute == 00:
            channel = client.get_channel(760182149839716423)
            await channel.send("<@&811801850771800134>")
            await channel.send("<@&811808231218610266>")
            await channel.send("<@&811802000463101963>")
            break # This break stops the loop
        elif cst.hour == 18 and cst.minute == 00:
            channel = client.get_channel(760182149839716423)
            await channel.send("<@&811801850771800134>")
            await channel.send("<@&811808231218610266>")
            await channel.send("<@&811802000463101963>")
            break # This break stops the loop


client.loop.create_task(time_event())
client.run('Token')
```

Comment: Just tried this method, same issue. It doesnt do anything